# geoman - how to access the resulting GeoJSON object after a feature has been removed in removalMode

Tags: leaflet, geojson, leaflet-geoman

I have a FeatureCollection from which I remove single Features. I can get the removed feature by adding an event listener ***pm:remove*** like following:

```js
layer.on('pm:remove', e => {
    // do stuff regarding the removed feature
    console.log(e.layer.feature)
});
```

I would like to also have access to the resulting FeatureCollection (from which the feature has been removed). how can I "*console.log()*" that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you added the layer to a LayerGroup / FeatureGroup? Then you can call `layergroup.toGeoJSON()`

Or if you use the default and adding the layers to the map, you can call `map.pm.getGeomanLayers(true).toGeoJSON()`.
`true` means that it returns a `L.FeatureGroup` instead of an array with the layers.

Comment: `map.pm.getGeomanLayers(true).toGeoJSON()` did the trick. thank you very much!